# How to change value with double quotes in XML file

Tags: xml, vbscript, attributes, nodes

I want to change `readback-enable="false"` to `"true"` in this XML file but it has double quotes, and can't sort it out.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like `replace( someString, "readback-enable=""false""", "readback-enable=""true""",1,-1,vbTextCompare)`? Note that **inner** double quotes are  **doubled**.

Comment: In any case, you should parse a `xml` file using [`XPath` (the XML Path language)](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @JosefZ , i resolved with your input this way: `strNewText = Replace(strText, "readback-rom-item readback-index=""0"" readback-enable=""false""", "readback-rom-item readback-index=""0"" readback-enable=""true""", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)`

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes can be tricky with string concatenation in VBscript. Note that char(34) is the ASCII equivalent.

Ex: In VBScript: `chr(34) & "Some" & chr(34) & " String" & chr(34)` would output "Some" String"

In your case, you could do a simple replace:

```
Replace((string you are using), "readback-enable=" & chr(34) & "false" & chr(34), "readback-enable=" & chr(34) & "true" & chr(34))
```

Hope this helps.